# Parse field having json data on query time solr

Tags: json, parsing, solr, field

I am using tika and ctakes to annotate solr documents with date information. I get my results as a json and I store it in a new field named `ctakes`, now I want to extract date out of my resultant json.

Is there a way I can achieve it easily by just plugging my json path in a solr query param?? I expect ctakes:DateAnnotation as a separate field so I can process it as date

`http://localhost:8983/solr/collection2/select?q=ctakes:*DateAnnotation*&wt=json&fl=ctakes`

Example query.

```
   ctakes[0]["ctakes:DateAnnotation"]
   ["10/12:918:923:", "10/12:960:965:", "10/12:997:1002:", "10/12:1038:1043:"]
```

Example json:

`ctakes: [
"[{"Content-Encoding":"UTF-8","Content-Length":"10061","Content-Type":"application/xhtml+xml; charset\u003dUTF-8","Content-Type-Hint":"text/html; charset\u003dutf-8","X-Parsed-By":["org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser","org.apache.tika.parser.ctakes.CTAKESParser","org.apache.tika.parser.html.HtmlParser"],"X-TIKA:parse_time_millis":"47811","ctakes:DateAnnotation":["10/12:918:923:","10/12:960:965:","10/12:997:1002:","10/12:1038:1043:"]}]"
]`